# How are children taught joining letters in Ecriture scolaire B?

Tags: orthographe, apprentissage

The question is not really about the French language, but about contemporary teaching in French schools. I hope there is an elementary school teacher that can answer this.

I am currently studying various scripts for a project visualising the process of writing, showing the movement of the pen when forming letters and words. As an example of a modern learners script, I have looked at the 2013 [polices de caractères pour l'enseignement de l'écriture](https://eduscol.education.fr/204/polices-de-caracteres-cursives-pour-l-enseignement-de-l-ecriture) and especially its *Modèle B* with letters that are very much formed like their printed counterparts.

While the authors of that script / font make a honest effort to maintain the traditional way letters are attached to each other when writing a word, there are some situations where their solutions, as can be seen from the published fonts, are problematic. From the [document d'accompagnement](https://eduscol.education.fr/document/15805/download):

> Ce modèle comporte essentiellement deux types de manière de lier les lettres : les liaisons horizontales et les liaisons diagonales...

> Dans le contexte de l’apprentissage, il sera important de bien veiller à savoir présenter toutes ces variations de formes et tous ses possibles sans le perdre. Si l’identité du mot est bien marquée, en revanche un décalage existe cette fois entre l’apprentissage des lettres et leur intégrité avec celles qu’elles ont dans les mots.

Problems arise for the horizontal attachments (at the upper line, the starting letters are o, r, v, w) when connected to the letters e, f and t. Let me show you how these letter combinations are rendered when using the font:

[image: font or script displaying ligatures of different two letter groups: ae, af, at and ra, rf, rt, all lowercase]

The basic concept, and I would expect that is what is taught to children when they learn to write, is when letters are attached to each other, the pen moves uninterrupted from writing one letter to the next.

In the first line, you can see how that would work (albeit not perfectly when compared to other scripts). Moving from a to e, the pen would rise from the base line to the middle and then take a turn to the right to form the loop for the e. From a to f or t, the pen would rise from the base line, going to the top of these letters, and come down again following the same form.

But in the second line, the concept as implemented in the font is broken. From r to e, the end of the connecting line does not meet the start of the loop. From r to f or t, the connecting line is shown to arrive horizontally, while the starting line of the next letter is coming down vertically. If you look closely, you can spot a difference in handling the horizontal stroke of the f and the z. The stroke of the f starts on top of the connecting line, left of the vertical form. The stroke of the t is shortened to only show on the right side of the vertical form.

Remember that both horizontal strokes are to be drawn **after** the body form of the letter. The *document d'accompagnement* makes it clear that ductus is important in teaching:

> La conformité au ductus doit être respectée. Il est important pour cela de ne pas considérer uniquement le résultat produit mais bien observer l’enfant en train d’écrire. Le respect du sens du tracé des lettres participe à une logique globale du tracé du mot et un « o » convenable visuellement mais tracé, en sens inverse du sens attendu, contrariera la poursuite du geste sur les autres lettres.

My question now is: If this script is used in elementary school, how is the execution of these *liaisons* / connections taught to the children? Is it left to them to make up their own mind how to form them, will the teacher divert from the way the font is presented, and is there a common directive for this?

**Edit:** From my research, "cursive" writing is taught in cycle 2, although the [document](https://eduscol.education.fr/document/14380/download) I found clearly refers to the Modèle A script, or older versions of essentially the same.

Please note that I am only asking about the specific Modèle B script, so answers about the suitability of this script for teaching or proposals to use another one are not what I am looking for.

The angle I am coming from is not trying to choose a script for teaching a child (I would certainly go with Modèle A), but to find out if you can have a script that maintains letter forms that closely resemble printed letters, and just the same can be written with the appearance of a natural movement of the pen. The practical usage of such a script in school would be a test of feasability, then.

Comment: I have personally never seen "Rom B" in school, only "Rom A", so I can't comment on how "Rom B" ligatures would work, but they look "impossible" to me :-)

Comment: Since this isn't about the language but the teaching of penmanship, it might not be a fit for the main site, but I encourage you to bring it up in chat at the very least since you have so much material here, yet you and another user keep deleting your comments.  I teach penmanship too and wish I had the resources and cultural support/history you do.

Comment: I don't know what to make of this fact, but I learned the word "ligature" much later, and not in the context of cursive writing of the French language, but rather when dealing with printing fonts, and ligatures for the Ancient Greek language.

Comment: @livresque For the comment, I deleted that myself.

Comment: @Frank Yes, tht is a printer's term. I used it because it also appears in the source, but there also the term "liaison" is used. I have a teaching book from 19th century US that talks of "joining" the letters.

Comment: @ccprog "Liaison" though in French would be used typically for "il-z-on" when pronouncing "ils ont". Maybe one can say "lier les lettres dans un mot", but "liaison" would refer to that pronunciation gotcha between words, so only when speaking.

Comment: Note that writing is first taught in kindergarten (cycle 1) and elementary school is only a follow up. Link to a document [L’écriture à l’école maternelle La forme des lettres](https://eduscol.education.fr/document/13564/download). *Ligature* is the proper technical term used by professionals when talking about cursive handwriting. The term is not used by the general public, but  kindergarten and primary school teachers, even if they don't use it, might  know the word.

Comment: If you enter "apprentissage écriture cursive en maternelle" in a search engine you will get directed to personal sites where teachers talk about their experiences.

Comment: @None I heard from children a term like *écriture en attaché*. In my experience, in maternelle, they learn little in terms of the technique of writing - more simply reproducing forms. Although it may depend on the age of the teacher - there seem to exist a great variety of pedagogical approaches, some are very "old school". I think though that technique really helps - but perhaps it depends on a child, as some are more prone to logical reasoning and algorithms, while others are more artistic.

Comment: *Écriture en attaché* is the layman's term for *écriture cursive*. Teachers among themselves will say *cursive* (so do official instructions), to parents they say *en attaché* (unless I expect they know parents can understand).

Comment: I wouldn't focus too much on Modèle B. It seems to be some experimental model that doesn't match traditional cursive writing which is Modèle A in France.

Comment: @jlliagre Agreed. Modèle A is what I learnt. I seriously doubt Modèle B can be written _en attaché_.

Comment: @Frank I think it's clear from the image that some ligatures can't be done and aren't supposed to. There is no ligature between q and r and between y and z. In this other B sheet I found, the example sentence has two "missing" ligatures : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/%C3%89criture_B-sample.svg/440px-%C3%89criture_B-sample.svg.png

Comment: @None I think *écriture en attaché* is more intended as a term for children than for their parents. I have no idea what balance the school programs strike between the scientific terminology and what the teachers are supposed to actually say in class, but I think it is worth trying it as a keyword in searching for materials for children.

Comment: @RogerVadim There might not be any need for a word in class, because _en attaché/cursive_ is the only style we learn(ed). It's just _écrire_ :-) I don't think you could write with block letters (all separate) in elementary school - at least it was not an option in my time, even all the way through high-school and after.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but mistoke the A & B. All school where I live show modele A, as like I told in my answer the liaison is natural to do on that modele, but school are switching to script anyhow.. which seem natural to me, they learn to read in script and was writting in cursive, now all in script.